# Result of a fetch request with Vuejs in a chrome extension

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-extension, fetch

Within my chrome extension I need to retrieve the token returned by my Oauth authentication process.
If the authentication is successful, I can't get the return value.
To implement this I have a method declared in my child component Login.vue (loaded from the parent App.vue) and in which a button calls my function via async login()

```js
async login() {
    const CLIENT_SECRET = "***********************************";
    const redirectURL = browser.identity.getRedirectURL();
    const clientID = "*********";
    const scopes = "openid";

    let loginURL = `${urlAuth}/auth`;
    loginURL += `?client_id=${clientID}`;
    loginURL += "&response_type=code";
    loginURL += "&state = default";
    loginURL += `&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirectURL)}`;
    loginURL += `&scope=${encodeURIComponent(scopes)}`;
    let url = {};
    url = await browser.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
        interactive: true,
        url: loginURL,
    });
    let hash;
    const JsonUrl = {};
    const hashes = url.slice(url.indexOf("?") + 1).split("&");
    for (let i = 0; i < hashes.length; i + 1) {
        hash = hashes[i].split("=");
        JsonUrl[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    const code = JsonUrl.code;
    const details = {
        redirect_uri: redirectURL,
        client_id: "********",
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
        code,
        client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
        scope: "openid",
    };
    let detailsBody = [];
    Object.keys(details).forEach(((property) => {
        const encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
        const encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(details[property]);
        detailsBody.push(`${encodedKey}=${encodedValue}`);
    }));
    detailsBody = detailsBody.join("&");
    // let user = {};
    await fetch(`${urlAuth}/token`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            },
            body: detailsBody,
        }).then((response) => (response.json()))
        .then((data) => {
            this.user = data.access_token;
        });
    this.$emit("access-token", this.user);
},
```

What I want

Get the result of my fetch request

What I get

The fetch request works. I am directed to the login page and the session appears on the admin interface of my oAuth server.
Since I'm in an extension, I can't send anything to the console. So I try to send the result in a component props which I fetch and display in the App.view parent via this code

```
<Login
    v-if="!isConnected"
    @access-token="updateToken($event)"
/>

...

props: {
    token: {
        type: String,
        default: "By default",
        required,
    },
    methods: {
        updateStatus(statut) {
            this.token = token;
        },
    }
}
```

But my props token keeps its default value. Nothing is transmitted and I don't even know if the fetch result is retrieved.
A little help would be appreciated.
Thanks :)

Comment: Fetch request seem not to works. The laucnhAuthWebFlow, qorks but i can't retrieve the result cleaning some code. I just try to get result of :
url = browser.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
        interactive: true,
        url: loginURL,
      }).then((response) => (response.json()))
        .then((response) => { this.data = response; return response; });
      url.then((result) => result.json())
        .then((result) => { console.log(result); });
Don't works... and don't understand why

Comment: Your `props` object is missing a closing semicolon, is that just a typo from copying code into your question?